# Delete records from table to reduce disk space

Tags: sql-server-2008

I tried to increase my disk space by deleting the  some old records, but my disk space is reduced at the time of running delete query. So I cancelled that query execution.. but still the disk space is reduced.

What i need to do ? is any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting records does not automatically regain you disk space, as the disk space allocated to the database files stays the same. You in fact may increase the size of the transaction log!

If you have deleted a bunch of records it may be possible to regain some disk space.
First you'll need to determine how much disk space is actually used & how much is available.

The following script should tell you this (taken from [DBA Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7917/how-to-determine-used-free-space-within-sql-database-files) ):

```
SELECT RTRIM(name) AS [Segment Name], fileid AS [File Id], groupid AS [Group Id], filename AS [File Name],
   CAST(size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Size in MB],
   CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Space Used],
   CAST(size/128.0-(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Available Space],
   CAST((CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)))*100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Percent Used]
FROM sysfiles
ORDER BY groupid DESC
```

You can then use the command `DBCC SHRINKFILE` to shrink the files. - eg

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(1, 240000)
```

Would shrink the file with fileID = 1 to 240 GB.

Note however -

- Shrinking database files is a bad idea in general, as you will cause indexes to become fragmented, and hence cause performance problems.
- If you do resort to shrinking the file - make sure there is a reasonable amount of free space left after the shrink - probably at least 15%

If at all possible do not shrink the database file. Shrinking the transaction log file is less of a problem (ensure it is truncated first so there is space to shrink the file).

Read the Technet article here about managing the transaction log http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345382(v=sql.105).aspx

Maybe consider getting more storage space for your database...

Comment: upvoted for pointing out the drawbacks of `DBCC SHRINKFILE` as well as "If at all possible do not shrink the database file."  On behalf of SQL DBAs everywhere, thank you...